# Offline install of R on Ubuntu/Linux

Tags: software-installation, r

I will need to install R (http://www.r-project.org/) on a number of machines which do not have internet access; many of them will be running Windows, but I suspect some might run Linux, if so, likely Ubuntu (this is all the info I have at hand). The official R download page for Ubuntu (and other Linux distros, https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/) explains how to do it using sudo apt-get (as do numerous other tutorials on the web).

However, how does one go about doing that when there's no internet? Which files should I download and how should I install them? I looked into the folders listed on the aforementioned website, but there's gigabytes of files there, separated for each recent Ubuntu version. The computers I will have to install R on may or may not have the same version, and might have another distribution as well.

Being myself mainly a Windows user, I'm a bit lost here (I do have a Ubuntu VM, if that helps for solving the problem). For Mac and Windows there are installers in the R download section, but for Linux it just redirects to this page. I did already figure out how to deal with the installation of packages, and of RStudio, but installing core R puzzles me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The difficult method ...**

You download all the DEB installers from the official packages site with all its dependencies and then install them with the command `dpkg`.

[r-base](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/r-base) lists (all links point to vivid; if you use another release change the URLs)...

Depends:

- [r-base-core](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/r-base-core) (>= 3.1.2-2) GNU R core of statistical computation and graphics system
- [r-recommended](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/r-recommended) (= 3.1.2-2)
      GNU R collection of recommended packages [metapackage]

Recommends

- [r-base-html](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/r-base-html)
      GNU R html docs for statistical computing system functions
- [r-doc-html](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/r-doc-html)
      GNU R html manuals for statistical computing system

Suggests

- [ess](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/ess)
      Emacs mode for statistical programming and data analysis
- [r-doc-info](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/r-doc-info) or [r-doc-pdf](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/r-doc-pdf) 
      GNU R info or pdf manuals statistical computing system

You will need to drill down all the "depends" though.

---

**An easier method ...**

When your install "r" with the following 2 commands ([you can also use a mirror for the latest release](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README)):

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install r-base
```

... that system will install all files related to "r" on that system but they will also remain on your system in `/var/cache/apt/archives`. All you need is to copy them over and install them on the other machine.

Problem here *can* be that this system already has something installed that the other systems do not yet have...

---

The command `dpkg` can be used to install separate DEBs with

```
dpkg -i {packagename1} {packagename2} {packagename3} {packagename4}
```

Comment: The easier method seems more reasonable. So to confirm - I'll get the files using apt-get on my VM, copy and move the files from the archive to the host computer, and run `sudo dpkg -i filesfolder/*deb` - or, something that I just found in another answer: "launch Synaptic and select File -> Add Package Downloaded"? Also,I assume this won't work if the host has a different (i.e. non-vivid) release?

Comment: Yes and yes on the latter too :)

Comment: @user3554004 also see this http://askubuntu.com/a/650963/15811