# How to install VLC with no internet connection

Tags: software-installation, vlc, standalone-session

I need to install VNC in one Ubuntu machine. The problem is that machine is in a remote site with no internet access whatsoever.

I could download a VLC installer for Ubuntu and take it to the machine I want to install in, but...

The VLC site offers a "download" button but that button only calls the apt protocol. The site doesn't have a way to download a deb package or installer that I could take with me in a flash drive to install VLC in the isolated machine.

- What alternatives do I have?
- Can I somehow take the deb packages of a machine in which VLC is already installed? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

You can change your apt-cache-path temporarily to a specific folder and download your package:

```
sudo apt-get -o dir::cache::archives="/new/cache/is/here" --download-only install vlc
```

If vlc is already installed:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get -o dir::cache::archives="/new/cache/is/here" --download-only --reinstall install vlc
```

or you can use apt-offline :)

[repo management](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu)

[change apt-cache folder](https://abz89.wordpress.com/2010/02/11/change-an-apt-cache-folder-location/)

[apt download-only / apt-offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419268/how-do-i-download-a-package-from-apt-get-without-installing-it)

Comment: Doesn't work because VLC is already installed.

Comment: do you tried `apt-get clean`  and  then the command with `reinstall` instead of `install`?

Comment: Wouldn't that mess up my system? What are the side-effects of doing the clean thing?

Comment: apt-get clean --> empties your apt-cache . If you remove packages and want to install them again, they will be downloaded because they aren't in the cache anymore

Comment: E: invalid operation: reinstall

Comment: my fault .... --> `--reinstall install` https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/apt/apt-get

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26078/discussion-between-user2667549-and-user1598390).

Answer (score 0):

You can find the debian package on a machine where it is already installed under */var/cache/apt/archives*

As an alternative you can also download the binary packages from here, depending on your Ubuntu version:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/vivid/+source/vlc